# How to add resource/scope to the parameter on using serviceprincipal secret method?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, dynamics-365

Need to hit customer insights API with the token received from the below library.

https://developer.ci.ai.dynamics.com/

1.How to find the resource for the customer insights API.
2.How to add the scope/resource as the parameter to the below request

```
msRestNodeAuth.loginWithServicePrincipalSecretWithAuthResponse(clientId, secret,
tenantId).then((authres) => {
console.dir(authres, { depth: null })
}).catch((err) => {
console.log(err);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

When you add permissions in Azure AD app registration, we can find the resource for customer insights API is `https://azurecustomerinsights.com/`.

[image]

There is a `options?: AzureTokenCredentialsOptions` parameter in `loginWithServicePrincipalSecretWithAuthResponse` method.

See this [line](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-node/blob/master/runtime/ms-rest-azure/index.d.ts#L840):

`loginWithServicePrincipalSecretWithAuthResponse(clientId: string, secret: string, domain: string, options?: AzureTokenCredentialsOptions): Promise<AuthResponse>;`

You can set the scope/resource through `tokenAudience` in `AzureTokenCredentialsOptions`. See reference [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-node/blob/fa35b874c212ed71a56f8093ca8e1d959f661cfb/runtime/ms-rest-azure/index.d.ts#L369).